# How to sort contours?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, opencv

I am wondering if anyone can elucidate a strategy that is able to sort contours on a per-frame basis.

I am trying to detect 'events' - in this case an event is defined as growth of motion for 4 frames.

If a contour 'grows'/has a larger contour area for 4 consecutive frames, an event is logged and I must store and output the contour's center position for the first frame of growth.

If there is only one event to be detected, I can crudely detect the origin of the event by performing a pairwise check on a list of contour areas and if this becomes true, by taking the (currentFrameNo - 4) positional element of a contour positions list.

However, trying to detect multiple events seems like a completely different ball game.

On any given frame, there may be (n) amount of contours found. Each contour is passed into a candidate object, with attributes that characterize the contour, such as frame number, position, and contour size.

Ultimately I need a way of sorting these contours on a per-frame basis, such that I can organise them based upon their relative positions, and subsequently perform the pairwise check on the 'right list' of contours.

I am not sure whether I need multiple (4+) lists, one for each possible event and then on each frame pass the candidates in to a separate list based on closest center positions, or if I should continue to add them to a single list and subsequently query the list.

I am hoping that someone with more experience with using linq/sorting collections could help identify a suitable approach.

Thank you for taking the time to read this post.

```
public class CandidateList
{
    public List<Candidate> candidates;

    public CandidateList()
    {
        candidates = new List<Candidate> candidates;
    }

    public void Add(Candidate candidate)
    {
        candidates.Add(candidate)
    }
}

public class Candidate
{
    //Attributes shown in constructor.

    public Candidate(VectorOfPoint contour, int frameNumber, double contourSize, Point location)
    {
        Contour = contour;
        FrameNumber = frameNumber;
        ContourSize = contourSize;
        Location = location;
        Location_x = Location.X;
        Location_y = Location.Y;
    }
}

_vc = new VideoCapture(someURLorFilePath);
_candidates = new CandidateList();
_vc.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;

public void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mat _frame = new Mat(); 
    // read frame.. + other operations to get desired data.

    Mat _contourOutput = _frame.Clone();
    VectorOfVectorOfPoint _contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

    CvInvoke.FindContours(_contourOutput, _contours, new Mat(), RetrType.External, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

    // If there are any contours
    if (_contours.Size > 0)
    {
        // Iterate through contours
        for (var i = 0; i < _contours.Size; i++)
        {
            // Find contour area of each contour (VectorOfPoint)
            double _contourArea = CvInvoke.ContourArea(_contours[i]);

            // Find centre of contour
            Moments M = CvInvoke.Moments(_contours[i]);

            Point _contourCentre = new Point(Convert.ToInt16(M.M10 / M.M00), Convert.ToInt16(M.M01 / M.M00));

            //  Create a candidate based on frame number, contourSize and location
            Candidate _candidate = new Candidate(_contours[i], _currentFrameNo, _contourArea, _contourCentre);
            _candidates.Add(_candidate)                     

        }
    }

    _currentFrameNo ++
}
```

Here are pictures depicting a very likely scenario that I must deal with:

Frame 1 - Four candidates.

[image: Frame 1 - four candidates]

Frame 2 - Four candidates, slightly shifted position

[image: Frame 2 - four candidates]

Frame 3 - Four candidates, slightly shifted position

[image: Frame 3 - four candidates]

Frame 4 - four candidates, shifted position
 **Two events detected.** 
**Retrieve center positions from frame 1.**

[image: Frame 4 - Two events detected.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of [circular buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) to store the history of each candidate:

```
public class CandidateBufferList
{
    private List<CircularBuffer<Candidate>> _candidateList = new List<CircularBuffer<Candidate>>();   
    private void Add(Candidate candidate)
    {           
        //Find a matching buffer for the candidate based on distance. More on this later
        //here maxDistance is the maximum distance a candidate can move each frame
        var matches = _candidateList.Where(cb => Distance(candidate.Location, cb.Last.Location) < maxDistance);
        int matchCount = matches.Count();

        if (matchCount == 0)
        {
            var cb = new CircularBuffer<Candidate>();
            cb.Add(candidate);
            _candidateList.Add(cb);
        }
        else if (matchCount == 1)
        {
            var match = matches.First();
            if (match.Last.FrameNumber == candidate.FrameNumber)
            {
                // Ambiguous match 1.
                throw new Exception("A candidate was already added to this buffer this frame.");
            }
            match.Add(candidate);
        }
        else
        {
            // Ambiguous match 2.
            throw new Exception("More than one matching buffer was found for this candidate");
        }
    }

    public void Update(int frameNumber, List<Candidate> candidates)
    {
        candidates.ForEach(c => Add(c));
        //Remove buffers that didn't match this frame.
        _candidateList.RemoveAll(cb => cb.Last.FrameNumber != frameNumber);
    }

    public List<Point> GetEvents()
    {
        return _candidateList
            .Where(cb => ContourHasGrouwn(cb))                
            .Select(cb => cb.First.Location)
            .ToList();
    }

    private bool ContourHasGrouwn(CircularBuffer<Candidate> cb)
    {
        //if contour is not older than 4 frames
        if (!cb.IsFull) return false;

        for (int i = 1; i < cb.Size; i++)
        {
            if (cb[i].ContourSize < cb[i - 1].ContourSize) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And on each ProcessFrame:

```
//CandidateBufferList candidatesHistory
//List<Candidate> candidatesThisFrame
candidatesHistory.Update(frameNumber, candidatesThisFrame);
var events = candidatesHistory.GetEvents();
```

I thought I should mention, if you try to find a match just by distance, might or might not have issues, depending on your specific problem:

- a candidate might be closer to another candidates center, eg. a new candidate is added close to another one's center (ambiguous match 1)
- a candidate might get multiple matches, you can take the one with the smallest distance but how can you be sure that is correct? (ambiguous match 2)
- worse, you can have 2 candidates and both can be closer to the other one's center on the next frame.

---

Here is the `CircularBuffer` implementation:

```
class CircularBuffer<T>
{
    private const int _size = 4;
    private int _index;
    private T[] _elements = new T[_size];

    public int Size => _size;
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public bool IsFull => Count == Size;

    public T this[int i] => _elements[(_index + i)%_size];
    public T First => this[0];
    public T Last => this[_size-1];

    public void Add(T element)
    {
        _elements[_index] = element;
        _index = (_index+1) % _size;
        if (Count < _size) Count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand all correctly. Basically that sounds like a tracking task.

You probably want to track your contours frame by frame, the "same" contour in the frame *f+1* having a near position to the one in the frame *f*. You could achive that by having a, say, TrackedContour class, which holds the history of the last 4 (or more, if you want) Countours.

The matching of a contour in frame *f+1* to some in frame *f* could be done by pairwise comparison of the contours, that would be easy to implement but ineficient for many contours, *n (n-1) / 2* comparisons for n contours. To make it more efficient, in a 2 dimensional space, one could hold the TrackedContours in 2 lists, one sorted by *X*, the other by *Y* coordinate. Then the count of new contours to be checked is reduced, because one has only to check those with "similiar" *X* and *Y*.

So basically the stratagy would be:

- Hold your TrackedContours in 2 sorted lists.
- Do frame by frame matching.
- Maintain the Contour History in your TrackedContours.
- Detect event conditions and look up in history for needed properties.

Hope this helps.